# Can Cheek bone grow bigger and wider in adulthood when you gain weight?

Tags: medications, plastic-surgery, obesity

From somewhere, I might have been heard that If you gain weight even in your adulthood when your growth has been finished, Facial bones can grow because obesity causes hormone balance problems(such as Growth hormone) or metabolic abnormalities 
and although you lose my weight, grown facial bone don't change to its previous size so you have wider facial bones.

Many Celebrities who became obese and returned to normal weight when they're in adulthood seem like their facial bone has been bigger and wider.

So what I want to know is it possible that facial bones grows bigger and wider in width (espescially temporal bones besides eyes, zygomatic bones) because of hormonal or metabolic imbalance caused by obesity.

Comment: Nope, not really. Also, please take the [tour] and visit our [ask] page.

Comment: Bones don't grow in adulthood, hormones or not. The appearance of celebrities is utterly irrelevant and usually involves plastic surgery.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with body _height,_ so is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Excessive calorie intake results in an increase of the body fat tissue but not muscle or bone tissue. Obesity does not make your bones thicker or longer. I don't have any source to back up this, but fat accumulates in fat cells and there are no or very few fat cells in the bone walls.

In adults with [acromegaly](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/acromegaly/symptoms-causes/syc-20351222), which is a hormonal disorder caused by increased production of the growth hormone (usually by a pituitary tumor), cheek bones, some other facial bones and bones in the hands and feet become bigger. Here are some [pictures](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=929&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=mNwjW4DuK8G96ATH24-wBQ&q=acromegaly&oq=acromegaly&gs_l=img.3..0i67k1j0l9.228034.229042.0.229450.12.7.0.0.0.0.104.583.6j1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.img..10.1.103....0.ef095ws4Zp8).